# How to calculate the metric for signal of alarm of time series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, calculation

I have time series of data where it response will give true (1) or false (0). Since my concern is to know whether the **forecast can give signal or alarm before actual true happen**. Hence using confusion matrix and f1-score this metric calculation is not representative of my concern.

Let say I have this kind of time series data.

```
date = ['2013-01-01 14:00', '2013-01-01 15:00', '2013-01-01 16:00', '2013-01-01 17:00',
 '2013-01-01 18:00', '2013-01-01 19:00', '2013-01-01 20:00', '2013-01-01 21:00',
 '2013-01-01 22:00', '2013-01-01 23:00', '2013-01-02 00:00', '2013-01-02 01:00',
 '2013-01-02 02:00', '2013-01-02 03:00', '2013-01-02 04:00', '2013-01-02 05:00',
 '2013-01-02 06:00', '2013-01-02 07:00', '2013-01-02 08:00', '2013-01-02 09:00',
 '2013-01-02 10:00', '2013-01-02 11:00', '2013-01-02 12:00', '2013-01-02 13:00',
 '2013-01-02 14:00', '2013-01-02 15:00', '2013-01-02 16:00', '2013-01-02 17:00',
 '2013-01-02 18:00', '2013-01-02 19:00', '2013-01-02 20:00', '2013-01-02 21:00',
 '2013-01-02 22:00', '2013-01-02 23:00', '2013-01-03 00:00', '2013-01-03 01:00',
 '2013-01-03 02:00', '2013-01-03 03:00', '2013-01-03 04:00', '2013-01-03 05:00',
 '2013-01-03 06:00', '2013-01-03 07:00', '2013-01-03 08:00', '2013-01-03 09:00',
 '2013-01-03 10:00', '2013-01-03 11:00', '2013-01-03 12:00', '2013-01-03 13:00',
 '2013-01-03 14:00', '2013-01-03 15:00', '2013-01-03 16:00', '2013-01-03 17:00',
 '2013-01-03 18:00', '2013-01-03 19:00', '2013-01-03 20:00', '2013-01-03 21:00',
 '2013-01-03 22:00', '2013-01-03 23:00', '2013-01-04 00:00', '2013-01-04 01:00',
 '2013-01-04 02:00', '2013-01-04 03:00', '2013-01-04 04:00', '2013-01-04 05:00',
 '2013-01-04 06:00', '2013-01-04 07:00', '2013-01-04 08:00', '2013-01-04 09:00',
 '2013-01-04 10:00', '2013-01-04 11:00', '2013-01-04 12:00', '2013-01-04 13:00',
 '2013-01-04 14:00', '2013-01-04 15:00', '2013-01-04 16:00', '2013-01-04 17:00',
 '2013-01-04 18:00', '2013-01-04 19:00', '2013-01-04 20:00', '2013-01-04 21:00',
 '2013-01-04 22:00', '2013-01-04 23:00', '2013-01-05 00:00', '2013-01-05 01:00',
 '2013-01-05 02:00', '2013-01-05 03:00', '2013-01-05 04:00', '2013-01-05 05:00',
 '2013-01-05 06:00', '2013-01-05 07:00', '2013-01-05 08:00', '2013-01-05 09:00',
 '2013-01-05 10:00', '2013-01-05 11:00', '2013-01-05 12:00', '2013-01-05 13:00',
 '2013-01-05 14:00', '2013-01-05 15:00', '2013-01-05 16:00', '2013-01-05 17:00']

actual = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
predict = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['actual'] = actual
df['predict'] = predict
```

[image]

From the picture I attach, the yellow highlight show the predict unable to give signature.

The only way I could identify whether its good predict or not. Are by identify the shifting (from 0 to 1) in the actual and try to compare with the predict.

```
df1 = df[df['actual'].where((df['actual'].shift(0)==1)&(df['actual'].shift(1)==0)).notnull()]['predict']
val = 100*(df1.sum()/len(df1))

# if val = 0, no indicator; if val > 0, have indicator
print('only {:.2f}% have signal'.format(val, len(df1)))
```

```
# only 80.00% have signal
```

Is there any reliable metric calculation, because what I see from the prediction, there are some prediction give late prediction. Hence by calculating based on the shifting (which I using) will not give any information, the model are late forecast or giving false alarm.